# C++ Open file seems to ruin file after run

Tags: c++, fstream

Simply put, I double click on image1 in its file and it opens. I run the code bellow to open image1 and nothing comes up. So I go into the file with image1 again, double click on it, and windows photo viewer said, "Windows Photo Viewer can't display this picture because the file is empty." I did this with two other test images and the same thing is happening. Nothing important has been lost but this method seems to be erasing whichever file it tries to open and I'm very curious as to why and how I can fix it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

void main()
{
    std::ofstream imagetest;
    imagetest.open("C:\\Users\\Filepath\\image1.jpg");
    std::chrono::milliseconds dura(2000);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(dura);//Kept the sleep in because I didn't know if having the console up would affect the file/image from opening. 
}
```

Comment: You want `std::ifstream` to open the file for reading.

Comment: Oh! What should I be replacing with it? Or what should I be looking at in order to get the result I'm looking for?

Comment: `std::ifstream imagetest;`, read into a data structure, and output another file?

Comment: if you expect that open will open a windows with an image in it your are far from what open does. open just prepeare the file to be written to, then it just empty it at program exit. see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/open/

Comment: made the changes with std::ifstream and nothing is being erased which is good. But I'm not not opening the file for some reason. Would that be ios::in?

Answer (score 4):

C++ is at lower level than scripts. open does not mean START.
You will have to execute a batch script with START C:\Users\Filepath\image1.jpg.
Or to learn many more libraries to do that in C++...

Comment: Do you know of any good libraries I should start researching?

Comment: see answer of michaelwayman which gives you ShellExecute function that allows you to run from a C/C++ code what you would have typed from a command prompt. You can even specify the viewer you want to open. Or you can write you own viewer...

Answer (score 3):

`ofstream` stands for “output file stream”. In addition to creating files that doesn’t exist, it also erases the contents of files that do exist. So you are opening an existing file for writing, and blowing away its contents in the process. You probably want `ifstream`, “input file stream”, for reading.

If you want to “open” the file in the sense of launching the default Windows application to read the file, you can use the Windows `start` command via `system`:

```
system("start \"C:\\Users\\Filepath\\image1.jpg\"");
```

Or the Windows [`ShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx) API:

```
#include <windows.h>

ShellExecute(
  NULL,
  "open",
  "C:\\Users\\Filepath\\image1.jpg",
  NULL,
  NULL,
  SW_SHOWNORMAL
);
```

Comment: i think he wants even more, that open will behave somehow like START command.

Comment: Just about, yes. Applied the ifstream and that fixed the file from being erased. Now I'm just trying to get the file to open.

Answer (score 2):

First,

```
std::ofstream imagetest;
```

is using the kernel to open the file for reading the file data..
this is probably what is corrupting the file from "opening" when you double click on it in windows

if you want to have windows open the image for viewing using the default application then you need a different method call because ofstream.open is not what you want.

try:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx

```
ShellExecute(NULL,"open","C:\\Users\\Filepath\\image1.jpg",NULL,NULL,SW_SHOW);
```

Comment: What requirements are needed to use ShellExecute and SW_SHOW? Both are reading as undefined.

Comment: answer is in above documentation , in Header section "Shellapi.h" that mean you have to #include that header to be able to compile with ( and give the Library to the linker, but this might be in default library path ).

Answer (score 1):

If you open a file stream for WRITE, then it will wipe all the content of that file, just like when you do that on a txt file. So you would always want to open the stream for read mode if you don't want that to happen